# Appending current URL parameters onto anchor link

Tags: javascript

At a page like

`https://www.example.com/?firstname=Steven&lastname=Smith&email=steve%40gmail.com&phone=0404555555`

I have a button (anchor link) `#ptsBlock_553944 .ptsCell:nth-of-type(1) .ptsEditArea.ptsInputShell` that links to `https://www.example.com/form`

I'd like to append the URL parameters from the current URL to the button's URL, so that the button's href is now `https://www.example.com/form/?firstname=Steven&lastname=Doig&email=steve%40gmail.com&phone=0404555555`

How can I do this with JavaScript please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Html select using select to change the link of a button with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336172/html-select-using-select-to-change-the-link-of-a-button-with-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `window.location.search`:

```
var url = "https://exmaple.com";
var newurl = url + window.location.search;
```

`newurl` will contain all the `get` (ex. `?something=something&something2=something5`) data.

To change the `href` of `a`:

```
var button = document.getElementById('#ptsBlock_553944');
button.href = button.href + window.location.search;
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I set the button's href value to `newurl`?

Comment: Is it a `button` or `a` element? If it's button is it a form submit button?

Comment: It's an `a` element

Comment: edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about supporting older browsers you can use the [URL API](https://caniuse.com/url) and [URLSearchParams](https://caniuse.com/urlsearchparams).

```
function appendCurrentUrlSearchParams(anchorElement) {
  const currUrlSearchParams = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams;
  const link = new URL(anchorElement.href);

  // uncomment this line if you want to clear query parameters already present in the anchor url
  // link.search = '';

  for (const entry of currUrlSearchParams.entries()) {
    link.searchParams.append(entry[ 0 ], entry[ 1 ]);
  }
  
  anchorElement.href = link.href;
}
```

Usage in your case:

```
appendCurrentUrlSearchParams(document.querySelector('#ptsBlock_553944 .ptsCell:nth-of-type(1) .ptsEditArea.ptsInputShell'));
```

Comment: I'm giving it `+1` because it will work in case when there are already some `GET` arguments - not the easiest solution for the OPs question (not such a case) but someone may need this one

Answer (score 0):

Read [Html select using select to change the link of a button with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336172/html-select-using-select-to-change-the-link-of-a-button-with-javascript)

specifically the section on

1. Get the element with something like document.getElement [MDN getElement Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
2. Change the .href of that element to what you want.

> 

```
function selectFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("selectopt").value;

    document.getElementById("mylink").innerHTML = x;
  
    document.getElementById("mylink").href = "http://www." + x + ".com";
  
}
```

> 

```
document.location.pathname = '/questions/69240453/appending- 
current-url-parameters-onto-anchor-link/69240510';

//get the document pathname I chose from document.location
let data = document.location.pathname;

let preUrlString = 'www.example.com/form';

let newString = preUrlString + data;

console.log(newString);
'www.example.com/form/questions/69240453/appending- 
current-url-parameters-onto-anchor-link/69240510'

document.getElementById("mylink").href = newString;
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I insert the URL parameters?

Comment: @Steve that make enough sense?